# Instruction less than one clock cycle

Tags: cycle, clock, instructions

I sometimes read that there are instructions which take less than a clock cycle - how is this possible? Or is this the value when pipelining and out-of-order comes in the game?

Comment: I think some CPUs can use IN AVERAGE less than one cycle per instruction because of pipelining

Comment: Not just pipelining.  Simultaneously performing several unrelated instructions is another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/Performance_Metrics

> (...)Historically, all early computers used many clock cycles during
>   the execution of even the simplest instruction. During the RISC
>   revolution, many designers focused on reducing this factor closer to
>   the apparent minimum of 1 cycle per instruction. We will discuss some
>   of the techniques used later in this book. Since then, CPUs that use
>   techniques such as superscalar execution and multicore computing have
>   reduced this even further. **Such CPUs can (on average) use less than 1
>   cycle per instruction**.
>
> "CPI" is a throughput measure of how many instructions are completed
>   (on average) for a given number of clocks. A CPU that can complete, on
>   average, 2 instructions per cycle (a CPI of 0.5) may have a 20 stage
>   pipeline, which inevitably causes a 20 cycle latency between an
>   instruction fetch to the completion of that instruction. We ignore
>   those 20 cycles when we calculate CPI.(...)